# MauiWebChromeClient not triggering OnProgressChanged

Tags: maui

Im trying to find out progress of page loading inside webview.

this is my MainPage.xaml.cs code :

```
namespace MauiApp2 {
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        int count = 0;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        void mywebview_Navigating(System.Object sender, Microsoft.Maui.Controls.WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
        {
#if ANDROID

            Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.WebViewHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("Custom", (handler, view) =>
            {
                handler.PlatformView.Settings.CacheMode = Android.Webkit.CacheModes.Default;
                handler.PlatformView.Settings.SetAppCacheEnabled(true);
                handler.PlatformView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                handler.PlatformView.SetWebChromeClient(new CustomWebViewClient(handler));
            });  
#endif
        }
    } }
```

and my CustomWebViewCLient.cs :

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Webkit;
using MauiApp2.Services;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform;
using Microsoft.Maui.Handlers;
using Microsoft.Maui.Platform;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebView = Android.Webkit.WebView;


    namespace MauiApp2.Platforms.Android
    {
        public class CustomWebViewClient : MauiWebChromeClient
        {
            private readonly Activity context;
            SpinnerPopup popup = new SpinnerPopup();
    
            public CustomWebViewClient(IWebViewHandler handler) : base(handler)
            {
                this.context = Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Platform.CurrentActivity;
            }
            public override void OnProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(newProgress);
            }
    
        }
    }
```

Nothing shows in output windows while pages getting load.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put the code in the Page's `OnHandlerChanged` method, such as:

In the xaml:

```
<WebView x:Name="web" Source="" HeightRequest="800"/>
```

And in the code behind:

```
protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
{
    base.OnHandlerChanged();

#if ANDROID
   var webview = web.Handler.PlatformView as Android.Webkit.WebView;
   webview.Settings.CacheMode = Android.Webkit.CacheModes.Default;
   webview.Settings.SetAppCacheEnabled(true);
   webview.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
   webview.SetWebChromeClient(new CustomWebViewClient(web.Handler as WebViewHandler));
#endif
}
```

You can add a breakpoint at the `OnProgressChanged` method to check if it is called or not.